# Improving spacy entity accuracy for location named entities

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

This is my first time working with Spacy and apologies if this question is pretty standard. I have gone through a lot of questions here but haven't found something that answers my question.

I have block of text (3-5 lines). The first 1-2 lines can contain names of individuals or organization. The next 2 and 3 contain addresses.There are some exceptions but this is generally the standard input.

**Examples**

1.
John Doe
9308 EAST MILL AVE.
ONALSKA WI 54650

2.
/1234567890
JANE DOE
277 LOWER RIVER RD
CAMDEN, NJ 08105

3.
XYZ CONSTRUCTION GROUP
4 VALLEY RD.
SULPHUR, LA 70663

4.
/0987654321
ABC FASHION BOARD
3 ARNOLD ROAD
SUITE 6598 MIAMI FL 33126
UNITED STATES

**The objective is to identify all persons, organizations, and locations from this block of text.**

Spacy is having some difficulty classifying locations. I added a few patterns to the nlp pipe and classification improved marginally. Code below:

```
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
patterns = [{"label": "LOC", "pattern": [{'IS_ALPHA': True},{'LOWER': 'rd'}]}
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
nlp.pipe_names
```

I wanted to know:

1. Since this input is so standard, can we train the spacy model to recognize this and maybe that improves classification?
2. Can we extract a list of Geographical entities to overwrite prediction. not sure if this is a good idea.

Any other suggestions on improving the overall accuracy are welcome.

Comment: Can you add a few examples of your data? Context really matters for spaCy. So, your data will determine the methodology to tackle your problem.

Comment: added 4 examples. hope that helps?